# How can I avoid the titleEdgeInsets' was deprecated warning / Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uibutton

I'm trying to make the warning `'titleEdgeInsets' was deprecated in iOS 15.0: This property is ignored when using UIButtonConfiguration` disappear.

At first, I used

`InfosButton.titleEdgeInsets.top = height*0.08`

`InfosButton.titleEdgeInsets.right = width*0.04`

But I got the following warning :

`'titleEdgeInsets' was deprecated in iOS 15.0: This property is ignored when using UIButtonConfiguration`

So I then used :

`InfosButton.configuration?.contentInsets = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: height*0.08, leading: width*0.04, bottom: 0, trailing: 0)`

But now, I can't adjust the image and the button title positions separately, I just get access to contentInsets and not titleEdgeInsets and imageEdgeInsets.

Anyone can help me?

Comment: If you are **NOT** using a `UIButtonConfiguration` button, you can ignore that warning. If you **ARE** using a `UIButtonConfiguration` button, you can look into `.titlePadding` and `.imagePadding`. If that does not give you your desired output, you may want to stick with the "old-style non-UIButtonConfiguration" buttons.